# Swift: joined(separator: "\br")

Tags: arrays, swift

In my array I need to separate the items with \br

When I try to do:

```
nameArray.joined(separator: "\br") = ["Peter", "John", "Frank"]
```

Swift tells me:

> "Cannot assign to value: function call returns immutable value"
>   "Invalid escape sequence in literal"

How can I insert \br after each item?

Comment: The error message means what is says: The result of `joined(...` is immutable and you can't assign anything to it. And the second error says you have to escape the backslash with another backslash (`"\\br"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
let nameArray = ["Peter", "John", "Frank"]
let str = nameArray.joined(separator: "\\br")
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the “Invalid escape sequence in literal” error message: Looks like you want to join the strings using a line break. If I’m guessing correctly, this would be the correct syntax:

```
.joined(separator: "\n")
```